# SuperMicro: Does X11DPH-T fit into Superchassis SC743AC-1200B-SQ?

Tags: supermicro

I bought a SuperWorkstation 7049A-T (https://www.supermicro.com/products/system/4U/7049/SYS-7049A-T.cfm) which has a X11DAi-N Motherboard (https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C620/X11DAi-N.cfm) and a SC743AC-1200B-SQ chassis (https://www.supermicro.com/products/chassis/4U/743/SC743AC-1200B-SQ).

Now I figured that I‘d rather want an X11DPH-T Motherboard (https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C620/X11DPH-T.cfm)

Now, the chassis and the dph-t are not listed in each other‘s ‚optimized for‘ section, but I wonder if it will be compatible nevertheless? Formfactor is the same and the two motherboards look pretty much identical

Comment: MB: **Dimensions 
12" x 13" (30.48cm x 33.02cm)**, Chassis: 4U chassis - supports for maximum motherboard sizes: **12" x 13" E-ATX and ATX**

Answer (score 2):

The spec sheets you listed there have identical physical specs:

```
Physical Stats
Form Factor:    E-ATX
Dimensions:     12" x 13" (30.48cm x 33.02cm)
```

So physically you should be able to swap those motherboards without issue. The I/O shield is going to be different between the motherboards, so hopefully that chassis has a hole for the I/O shield and hasn't fixed it in the chassis itself.